# serial asynchronous calls for each item in an array

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

given an array of objects, I would like to make an asynchronous call for each object, and then not proceed to the next object until the asynchronous call for the previous object completes.

I have this working code:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
#import <TRVSMonitor/TRVSMonitor.h>

@interface FSReactiveCocoaArraySignalProcessingTests : XCTestCase{
    NSArray *sequence;
}
@end

@implementation FSReactiveCocoaArraySignalProcessingTests

-(void)setUp{
    [super setUp];
    sequence = @[@"dog", @"cat", @"mouse", @"rabbit", @"wallabee"];
}

-(void)tearDown{
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)test_maybe_using_the_disposable_method_of_creating_a_signal{
    TRVSMonitor *monitor = [TRVSMonitor monitor];
    RACSignal *resultingSignal = [[sequence.rac_sequence
                                   map:^(NSString *val){
                                       return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
                                           NSLog(@"returning signal for %@", val);
                                           [[self fakeApiCall:val]
                                            subscribeNext:^(id next){
                                                [subscriber sendNext:next];
                                            }
                                            completed:^{
                                                [subscriber sendCompleted];
                                            }];
                                           return nil;
                                       }];
                                   }]
                                  foldLeftWithStart:[RACSignal empty]
                                  reduce:^RACSignal *(RACSignal *left, RACSignal *right){
                                      return [left
                                              then:^{
                                                  return [right doNext:^(RACTuple *tuple){
                                                      //real world side effect for processing end of call.
                                                      RACTupleUnpack(NSString *val, NSNumber *len) = tuple;
                                                      NSLog(@"word %@ has %@ chars", val, len);
                                                  }];
                                              }];
                                  }];

    [resultingSignal subscribeCompleted:^{
         NSLog(@"FIN!");
         [monitor signal];
     }];

    XCTAssertTrue([monitor waitWithTimeout:10]);
}

//Returns a new signal that returns a RACTuple<NSString *, NSNumber *>
-(RACSignal *)fakeApiCall:(NSString *)val{
    return [[RACSignal return:RACTuplePack(val, @(val.length))]
      delay:.5];
}
@end
```

https://gist.github.com/jonnolen/b0e071b8dd202f7ed912

The question:  is there a "more reactive" way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this more of a thought exercise or a working within a real problem?

Comment: This is working within a real problem.  Given [a, b, c, d] the results of f(a) are needed to process f(b) and the results of f(b) are needed to process f(c), etc   in the example of above that isn't what is being done, but a side effect of f(a) is a db update that f(b) looks for.